# Where is the Angular 7 build path to add a src to?

Tags: angular, webpack, stripe-payments, angular7

I am using this [stripe-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe-angular) to implement stripe credit card processing.  I am not able to access window.Stripe after following the directions on the site.

This is my component file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
import { CreditCardService } from '../_services/creditcard.service'
import { StripeScriptTag } from "stripe-angular"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stripe',
  templateUrl: './stripe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stripe.component.css']
})
export class StripeComponent {

  private publishableKey:string = `${environment.stripeKey}`;

  constructor(private creditCardService: CreditCardService,
  public StripeScriptTag:StripeScriptTag) {
  console.log('publishable key ',`${environment.stripeKey}` )
  console.log('window.Stripe ', window.Stripe )
  }
```

The error is, "**Property 'Stripe' does not exist on type 'Window'.**"

This code is placed in the component and main index html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

That exposes Stripe but window does not find it.

I read that I should add that path to the webpack build path.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When I replaced window.Stripe to just Stripe the error went away and added Stripe:any